# Not able to pass imageview into Glide

Tags: java, android, json, android-imageview, android-glide

I tried to load Image from *Glide* on my *ImageView menagerie*

but it doesn't show image on my imageView;

My image view ID is menagerie

loading image from JSON Object from an url.

showing error on ::--

```
Glide.with(this).load(url).into(menagerie);
```

Below is the full
code:--

```
public void loadMore() {


   String url = "http://my-json-feed";

   JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest 
                                         (Request.Method.get, 
                                         url, null, new 
                                         Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
 

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

         String url = null;
          try {
           url = response.getString("url");
          } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrack();
          }

        Glide.with(this).load(url).into(menagerie);
     }
   }
}
```

[this is my activity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGrHB.jpg%60)

Comment: It's better to add your code as text not image.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

you are having an error at `with.(this)`

use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`

you are having error at `.into(menagerie)`

you should never pass id

you need to initialized a variable and pass an id to it

like this-->

```
    ImageView ImageView;
    ...
    .
    .
    onCreate()...{
    . 
    .
     ImageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.menagerie);


     .
     .
```

then you should do this-->

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(url)
            .into(ImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getApplicationContext() instead, like this  Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);